# Changing default window position in PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, window, pycharm

How do I change the default window position? The output window when I run a script defaults to the bottom, but I prefer it to the left, so every time I need to click through this menu. I haven't been able to find such a setting, or a guide online. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your current tool window layout as the default tool window layout by going to **Window -> Store Current Layout as Default** in the menu bar.

[image]

For more about tool window manipulation, visit [here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html)

Comment: Yout '[here]' isn't a link

Comment: Sorry, fixed now :)